# How to print out value of a variable during debugging in Netbeans?

Tags: xcode, debugging, variables, netbeans

In xcode during debugging, it is possible to print out the value of a variable at that particular stage. I was just wondering if there is a similar function in Netbeans? If not, what Java IDE does?

Comment: set breakpoints 
[or]
Window -> Debugger -> Variables
[or] 
ALT+SHIFT+1 
[or] 
CTRL + F9 to change values

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried the following methods:

Put a breakpoint on the line where you want to see the value. Run the debugger on that file and switch to the 'Variables' tab (`Window > Debugger > Variables`). This will display the values of your variables at that breakpoint. These rows might also have children rows - eg. If there was an array named `myArray`, you can click on the `+` symbol next to it to see each elements value.

You can also evaluate conditionals by going `'Debug' > 'Evaluate Expression'`. For example, in the iterating loop over 'myArray', you could enter `myArray[2] == 5` and click the green `->` arrow to evaluate this. If the value of that element was 5, this would indicate the expression, type (`boolean` in this example), and output of that test.

**OR**

- Insert your breakpoint wherever you'd like to monitor the variable.
- Right-click the breakpoint and select 'Breakpoint > Properties'.
- Set the suspend to "No thread (continue)".
- Then just fill in the corresponding field  with the format of `{=<variable name>}`. So, for example entering: "`myVar value @ L30 is: {=myVar}`" will output "`myVar value @ L30 is: 1`" to the debugger console.

You shouldn't need to recompile. Just run under the debugger and switch to the console output.

Answer (score 1):

Set breakpoint and use the 'PO' keyword to print the variable.

```
ex: `NSString *string=@"String to print";`   in your code
```

if want to print this string in debugging mode, just you need to put breakpoint in front of this line and type `Po string` in log panel.

Comment: sorry, is this for netbeans or xcode? I'm actually asking if printing out variable values can be achieved in netbeans. But thanks for helping out!